# High CPU usage when using parse-server with clusters

Tags: node.js, express, parse-server

I am using latest version of parse-server(2.3.8) for my slots casino app and app is comunicating to server frequently just like real time game.

My server configuaration is -

DB Server - Mongo Atlas(M30 - 8GB RAM, 40GB storage), Mongodb 3.4
Parse Server - Rackspace(15GB RAM, 50GB Storage, 8 Core), Nodejs - 6.10.2

For multithread support i am using clustering using pm2(latest version). I am using 6 core from 8 for clustering.
Currently there is max 10-20 Concurrent users. Initial when i startup the parse server using clustering -

pm2 start main.js -i 6

The cpu usage us max 2% - 5%. After 1 day the cpu usage becomes 70% - 90% while the concurrent users are 10-20 or less.

I am sharing image the process list by result of "$ top " command.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY0fV.png

Please help me how to minimize the cpu usage, where i am going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to see current running process ? to see what's going wrong, If you have some information like that, I'm here

Comment: Hi Julien, thank you for your reply. I just attaching image of process list https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY0fV.png